# Faster decoding with FFmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, streaming, video-streaming, bitrate

I am using `ffmpeg` for live stream processing. Basically, I compiled `ffmpeg` myself. Unfortunately, I notice that when the bitrate gets a bit high (> 15mbps H264), the decoding can not keep up with the incoming rate. I wonder the rate is not still very high.

I wonder, is there any flags to set, or maybe some tips to make `ffmpeg` decode faster or more efficient with live decoding? Or is there any flags that I can turn on? Like multi-threading? It's running/should run on CPU. But CPU usage is still not maximum.

We are running ffmpeg from C API as the base for the processing. [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/37ouryz3zr55fvh/indemand.ts?dl=0) is the sample `.ts` file that stalls the processing.

Comment: Show full command and log.

Comment: @Gyan there is no ffmpeg-specific error. Basically, the incoming rate is higher than what ffmpeg can decode, and so buffer after a while fills all memory.

Comment: Btw, we're using a 2017 version of ffmpeg. Does a 2019 improve performance with higher bitrate?

Comment: *the incoming rate is higher than what ffmpeg can decode, and so buffer after a while fills all memory* --> without looking at logs, I can't verify that. It also sounds very unlikely. I have transcoded 6K/8K clips (> **1200** mbps) and although processing gets slow on an i5/i7 with 16 gigs RAM, it does not stall.

Comment: Wow 1200 mbps! We are running ffmpeg from C code. Here is the sample video with 17mbps that stalls the engine: https://www.dropbox.com/s/37ouryz3zr55fvh/indemand.ts?dl=0

Comment: What are the demuxing / decoding / filtering / encoding / muxing flags set?

Comment: Need to verify those. But no filtering.َ Apparently after demux, there are some post processing past ffmpeg.

Comment: BTW, these are network stream. I guess the case might be different when reading from file.

Comment: Did you post to the mailing list as well?

Comment: No, what mail list?! Can you share it??

Comment: @Gyan and here is the build flags: https://www.dropbox.com/s/yecvqk97qz8m7iz/External_FFMpeg.txt?dl=0

Comment: Those are compile flags, Gyan was asking for flags that you are using when you run it.

Comment: I don't have it handy...have to ask colleagues...will share it soon.